# Show message "NO DATA FOUND" in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created SSRS report having 3 columns in it. Now, I have to show "NO DATA FOUND" message below report header. How can I achieve it. I cant not use report property "NO ROW" as I have to show Report Header also.

```
Followings are the fields in my Report tabix:
ContentId,
Version
ApprovedBy

I have tried following to show "NO DATA FOUND" message:
In Tabix textbox, I have added expression:
=IIF(Count(Fields!ContentId.Value)=0 OR IsNothing(Fields!ContentId.Value)=true,"NO DATA FOUND.",NOTHING)
```

But, It is not working. Please suggest me, where I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I imagine it is not working is you have this textbox in a data (non-header) row of the tablix. Since there is no data, this row will be repeated exactly zero times.

You should be able to do either of the following:

- Add a header row to the table with the text "NO DATA FOUND" which is hidden on `=Count(Fields!ContentId.Value) > 0`.
- Add a normal textbox outside of the tablix below the table, similar to the above. You may need to explicitly specify the data source. If it is hidden, the space should be consumed and the report will display as normal.

Comment: Hi, I have added textbox just below the header row with "=IIF(Count(Fields!ContentId.Value)=0 OR IsNothing(Fields!ContentId.Value)=true,"NO DATA FOUND.",NOTHING)" expression.

Comment: Is it a in a header row?

Comment: How to add Header Row?

Comment: I have added above expression to textbox which I have added above header row. So, its working properly but I have to show message just below Header row and I am unable to added Header row there.

Comment: Not sure why you are "unable" to add a header row there. Is there something in your row that prevents anything from coming below it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following if using a table...since the table doesn't have the `NoRowsMessage` feature:

**1.**  Add a text box with expression =IIF(Count(Some Field,"DataSet1")=0,"No Data Returned", nothing)

**2.**  Then, set the visibility of this textbox as =IIF(Count(Some Field,"DataSet1")=0,False,True)